# How to notify a python client from node server?

Tags: python, node.js, redis, node-redis, redis-py

I have a node process which is currently receiving  POST requests at https://company/api/bats_hook/. I want to notify a python process whenever a job comes in. I am using node_redis and redis-py, the implementation looks like below.

Following code works great locally when the node process is running locally, when I push the  node endpoint to a server, I don't seem to get the events?

How do I subscribe to the endpoint on the server from python client? What is missing? I do have the redis server deployed on the server https://company/api/bats_hook/

### javascript

```js
    var redis = require("redis"),
    //redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient = redis.createClient({url: process.env.REDIS_URL});

    app.post("/api/bats_holder", (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.query.params)
      console.log(req.body)
      console.log(req.body.name)
      // This publishes a message to the "bats hook channel"
      redisClient.publish("bats hook channel", JSON.stringify({
        params: req.query.params,
        body: req.body,
      }));
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "BATS object",
        posts: req.body
      }); 
    });
```

### python

```py
    import redis

    r = redis.Redis()
    p = r.pubsub()
    p.subscribe('bats hook channel')

    # This blocks and reads any messages from the "bats hook channel" as they come in
    for message in p.listen():
        print(message)
```

Comment: Can you clarify on where the redis server is running, along with your node server and python client? Are all three of them running on the same server, or on their own?

Comment: Please also provide any error logs from the node script and what the env configs are for e.g. `REDIS_URL` for both nodem python and redis process.

Comment: Following is the server documentation `Your application will get an environment variable called REDIS_URL, which takes the form of:

redis://redisdb:<password>@<host>:<port>/0
Environment Variables REDIS_URL`

Comment: @alex067 - redis and node server are running on the same server,the python client is running  locally on my mac...

Comment: @Ritz then as I mentioned in an answer you need to configure common Redis for both of them using REDIS_URL. Check if it will help.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you haven't configured Redis URL in python script. That's why it uses endpoint on localhost by default. Update your script with following.

```py
import os
import redis

REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')

r = redis.from_url(REDIS_URL)
p = r.pubsub()
p.subscribe('bats hook channel')

# This blocks and reads any messages from the "bats hook channel" as they come in
for message in p.listen():
    print(message)
```

More details and examples in [documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis.from_url).

Comment: I am trying to figure out what exactly is the REDIS_URL variable so that I can use that in the python client,how do I get that from the python client? redis and nodejs are running on one server and the python client is running on its own

Comment: @Ritz where are you running it (Heroku/AWS/VPS)? How did you set variable for Node.js? You need to set the same for python script. It can be not environment variable but some config file or other way. But what I wanted to say by this answer - you need to provide it.

Comment: @Ritz have you found how to set this variable and check if it works now for you?

Comment: Sounds like I cannot access the REDIS_URL outside of the server,both the python script and the node.js should reside on the server

Comment: @Ritz I believe you can, but you need to figure out how to do that using your hosting. You can search for instructions or ask as a separate question on Stackoverflow.